# Listing two digit numbers in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use my program to average 3 grades I've got all the math down but I'm not sure how to use one `input` command to get 3 separate variable. for instance, the user is supposed to enter 3 grades in one input statement but how do I separate them? my method: `grade = list(input("Three test scores: "))` outputs `grade = ['2', '3', ',', ' ', '1', '2', ',', ' ', '5', '4']` when given `23, 12, 54` my desired output is `grade1 = 23` `grade2 = 12` `grade3 = 54` any help??

Comment: No need to convert a string to a list. you can split on the basis of `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
grades = input('Three test scores: ')
grade1, grade2, grade3 = grades.split(', ')
```

A little more general solution which treats any non-numeric characters (not just comma-space) as separators:

```
import re
grade1, grade2, grade3 = re.findall(r'\d+', grades)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to split the input using `.split(", ")`. This should return you back a list of strings.

Then use `map` to convert them to ints. `map` takes a function (in this case `int`) and applies that function over a sequence of values.

```
>>> inputs = input("Three test scores: ").split(", ")
Three test scores: 1, 2, 3
>>> grade1, grade2, grade3 = map(int, inputs)
>>> grade1
1
>>> grade2
2
>>> grade3
3
```

Or more compactly:

```
grade1, grade2, grade3 = map(int, input("Three test scores: ").split(", "))
```